# Not able to pass a value from one component to other component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the recently updated value of the dimensions object in the Navbar.js component in the Home.js component. I tried to pass a callback function as props to Navbar.js from Home.js (as Home.js is parent of Navbar.js) but I cannot store the newly updated value of dimensions state in Navbar.js. Also if I pass the dimensions state as a dependency in useEffect it leads to infinite loop. Please help me.

```
**Home.js component**

const Home = () => {
  const [heightNav, setHeightNav] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(heightNav);
  }, [heightNav]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar
        setHeight={(h) => {
          setHeightNav(() => h);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

**Navbar.js component**

const Navbar = ({ setHeight }) => {
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (refContainer.current) {
      setDimensions(() => {
        return {
          width: refContainer.current.offsetWidth,
          height: refContainer.current.offsetHeight,
        };
      });
      setHeight(dimensions.height);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <Container ref={refContainer}>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: You don't pass the height from `Home` to `Navbar` (but it's also set from `Navbar` so... it's already there). I'm not sure what issue you're having.

Comment: I want the heightNav state value in Home to store the value of dimensions of Nav but it does not store the actual value it stores {width: 0,height: 0} not the updated value of dimensions.

Comment: Your Navbar's `useEffect` has empty dependencies and will only run on mount? Have you tried adding `refContainer.current` as a dependency to it?

Comment: @M0nst3R yes it works on using refContainer.current  but can you tell why it worked because when I put dimensions in the dependency then it leads to infinte loop. So why does this not lead to infinite loop. Thanks

Comment: You put dimensions as a dependency to a function that changes dimensions, that's your infinite loop.

Comment: On the other hand, putting `refContainer.current` as a dependency just makes sure that the ref is fully present before setting the height in the parent, no infinite loop.

Comment: In other words since value  of refContainer.current does not change it keeps on referencing the same DOM element that's why right. Thanks a lot @M0nst3R for helping me out.

Comment: Exactly, `refContainer.current` will remain constant after it updates to the needed reference, thus the `useEffect()` stops triggering. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this for Navbar:-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const Navbar = ({ setHeight }) => {
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateDimensions = () => {
      if (refContainer.current) {
        setDimensions({
          width: refContainer.current.offsetWidth,
          height: refContainer.current.offsetHeight,
        });
      }
    };

    updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(dimensions.height);
  }, [dimensions.height, setHeight]);

  return <div ref={refContainer}>Navbar Content</div>;
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing dependencies in the useEffect of the navbar component. I have added setHeight to the dependency which will mount the component every time it is updated and render the updated values. This modified code might solve your problems!

```
**Home.js component**

const Home = () => {
  const [heightNav, setHeightNav] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(heightNav);
  }, [heightNav]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar
        setHeight={(h) => {
          setHeightNav(h);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

**Navbar.js component**

const Navbar = ({ setHeight }) => {
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
const updatedValues = () => {
 if (refContainer.current) {
      setDimensions(() => {
        return {
          width: refContainer.current.offsetWidth,
          height: refContainer.current.offsetHeight,
        };
      });

}
  useEffect(() => {
      updatedValues();
      setHeight(dimensions.height);
    }
  }, [setHeight]);
  return (
    <Container ref={refContainer}>
    </Container>
  );
};
```